# open/edit/save csv files with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Is there any php/mysql software that can pull data from a mysql database or a csv file, and allow you to edit, perhaps copy/paste new rows, then save this file as a csv?

needs to be web based. any pointers will help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191459/php-based-csv-editor

Answer (score 3):

Are the fgetcsv (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and fputcsv (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) functions sufficient?

In terms of fetching data from a mysql database:

```
$result = mysql_query($some_query);

$file = fopen('some_file', 'w');

$is_first = true;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 
   if($is_first) {
   
       fputcsv($file, array_keys($row));
       $is_first = false;
   }

   fputcsv($file, $row);

}

fclose($file);
```

Haven't tested it, but that will probably work to convert a mysql query result into a csv file, including the column names at the top of the file.

Comment: i was hoping there was something pre-made that i could learn from. Not really skilled enough to build this from scratch.

Comment: Kazar really pointed you in the right direction.  The description you mentioned doesnt sound like something that would be available in a 'generic' form.  Most cases where that sort of functionality is needed would be buried within a larger system.