# PHP-based CSV editor?

Tags: php, csv, editor

Does anyone know of an online CSV editor written in PHP that will allow a user to open, edit, and save a given CSV file?

All I can find are CSV classes and nothing that can handle dynamic files, just predefined lengths etc.

Comment: could you elaborate a tad on your requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parse the CSV file into array.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)  Then, use an array of arrays to populate a matrix of text boxes in your web page.  When you submit the form, read the data from `$_POST` and use `fputcsv()` to save it.

Think about validation, if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to open a file, edit it using a web based UI and save it? 
Why not use Google Docs?

EDIT: Its irritating when people vote you down without leaving a comment as to why...  Useless contributions...

Comment: +1 on downvotes, i think you where downvoted because the question asked for a PHP solution. Though google docs i good at CSV handling, so im upvoting you for suppling an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) would solve your issue. Basically it takes in CSV file and parses it out into an array.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2124-PHP-Retrieve-or-change-information-stored-in-CSV-files.html

Point it at a csv, tell it the delimiter, unique field and tell it to edit. Very simple to use. I've had an issue with the delete button but I only just tried it for the first time, I'm sure I can work that out.

Saved me some hours trying to build and test my own.

Edit: Worked out the issue with the unique column (or KeyFieldName as he calls it) don't have spaces in the name of that column (the first row of the csv)