# open and edit csv file directly in website

Tags: php, csv, yii, jquery-plugins, yii2

I have example.csv file in server website folder,

I want to create  a function like : anyone can able to open example.csv file and edit data  in that file and save it in same place through website click function

I try this

```
<a href='example.csv'>click</a>
```

But shows read-only or download directly.

any plugins are available for this.

thanks in advance

Comment: read this one [edit csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191587/6350167), maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use SQL, I recommend to use native import/export in SQL DB, and if you want to use some plugin and customizing it is not a trouble for you, take a look this [GridView Demo](http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo).